# What does Ramchal refer to, when he says to know “principles”?

Tags: mussar-ethics, ramchal

In his introduction to Derech HaShem, Ramchal mentions the importance of organized and systematic thinking by breaking things down into general principles.

He then details how he broke this Sefer down into “four parts”. Each part has chapters that are broken down into little ideas.

Are the general principles the four “parts” or the chapter headings?

Comment: If you are studying Derech Hashem I cannot recommend this guide at Torah.org highly enough, it breaks the salient points of each chapter down into extrenemely easy-to-understand bites: https://torah.org/learning/ramchal-classes-prologue/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ramchal is making a general point that in any subject, it is easier to learn by first mastering the basic concepts. As I remember it, the sefer Derech Hashem as a whole is meant to teach you the general concepts underlying statements of Chazal across Talmud and Midrash.